# SAP Hybris based ECommerce platform configuration

Tags: java, spring, e-commerce, sap-commerce-cloud

I will start to work with this platform next month so I need some advice beforehand.

Does the Spring Framework part uses the Java configuration or XML?

All in all I want to ask if I should learn how to use XML configuration with Spring?

Comment: I think this question is not for stackoverflow, but for programmers community. But if to answer, basically you can do everything without XML in Spring MVC (I do like that). But anyway XML will be (want you or not) part of your job.

Comment: Nowadays xlm is almost forgotten in the e-commerce development, don't you think so ?

Comment: Ooh alright, I have 1 year Spring development experience, however I never did Xml configuration, that got me worried.

Comment: I misunderstood your question. Configuring spring with XML is something different, but you will find it applicable mostly on old projects that started back then when Java config wasn't used. You will find many resources nowadays with XML configuration so you don't need to worry. If you know to configure with Java, then you will manage to do this in XML if need will arise, or search engines will help you. Currently is harder to find info on Java config than XML from what I found, but the examples grow in number every day

Answer (score 1):

Yes in hybris the Spring configuration is done using XML. There are also some annotations used, but the applicationcontext is defined in xml.

[Spring Framework in SAP Hybris Commerce](https://help.hybris.com/6.3.0/hcd/8c63621986691014a7e0a18695d7d410.html)

Comment: your link requires username and password. Are you sure you wanted to provide it this way?

Comment: @XMight Yes, all official hybris docs are private. I assume people working on hybris have an access to this site. It's not really important, it's just further reading for the OP. The question is answered anyway.